# Flask - url_for() missing arguments even after request.get fix

Tags: python, html, flask

I'm currently working with Flask, and I keep running into this error:

"profile_creation: missing 1 required positional argument: 'user'"

So, I looked at some posts on this site, and most of the answers involve adding `request.args.get()`. So, I did what I could with the posts and made edits to my code, but I'm still getting the error. This is what I have right now:

```
@app.route("/profile-creation", methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def profile_creation(user):
    user = request.args.get("x")
    form = ProfileForm()

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        ...

        return redirect(url_for('/home'))


@app.route("/register", methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def register():
    form = RegistrationForm()

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        hashed_password =     bcrypt.generate_password_hash(form.password.data).decode('utf-8')

        user = User(username = form.username.data, first_name = form.first_name.data, last_name = form.last_name.data,
            email = form.email.data, password = hashed_password)

    return redirect(url_for('profile_creation', x = user))
```

Both of these pages have to do with a user filling out forms with personal information (registering for an account, then posting some profile stuff, like age, etc.). Where am I going wrong here? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `user` is in the URL in the form `/profile-creation?user=my_user`, you use

```
@app.route("/profile-creation", methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def profile_creation(): # Note: no user argument here
    user = request.args.get("my_user")
```

if instead it's like `/profile-creation/my_user`

```
@app.route("/profile-creation/<user>", methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def profile_creation(user):
    # user argument will be set to 'my_user'
```

Comment: Thank you, that fixed it. If ``user`` is an instance of a User class, and I want the url to be ``/profile-creation/<user.username>``, where ``username`` is a string variable of ``user``, what is the correct way to do that? The above url seems to raise a malformed url error.

Comment: You mean where you have `return redirect(url_for('profile_creation', x = user))`?

Use `return redirect(url_for('profile_creation', x = user.username))` instead.

Remember that the URL is "just a string". Trying to use it with objects won't work.